# Proof using de Moivre's Theorem

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z=\cos\theta + i\sin\theta$

Show that
$$1+z = 2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin\frac{\theta}{2})$$

I don't even know how to start on this proof.

Comment: show that the real parts and imaginary parts are identical...

Comment: Expand the right hand side and use trigonometric formulae.

Comment: Wow, I thought you had to do some mathematical magic but in the end it's really easy, sorry guys. Should I delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just the double angle formulas in the real and complex parts.
$$\cos 2 \theta=2\cos^2\theta -1$$
$$\sin 2\theta=2\cos \theta \sin\theta$$